# AzureSQL PaaS Serverless and LTR

Tags: azure-sql-database, serverless, database-backups

All,

We have a **Azure SQL PaaS database** on **serverless** edition. Due to limitations inherent in serverless editions, we cannot setup a LTR beyond the daily backups being retained for a period of 5 weeks.

Just wanted to check how others are handling the LTR needs for the same for this edition for ***Monthly*** and ***Yearly*** backups

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your database as bacpac to an Storage Account. We are using weekly exports of the database on Saturdays, with a retention of one year for long-term backups.

The export will trigger a auto-resume of the database if the database was auto-paused.

We use an Azure Automation account and a PowerShell runbook to schedule the export of the database,